# How do I put an array on the POE heap and push or pop data?

Tags: arrays, perl, heap-memory, poe

How do I put an array on the [POE](http://search.cpan.org/dist/POE) heap, and push/pop data to/from it?

I'm trying to put the following array on the heap:

```
@commands = (
    ["quit",\&Harlie::Commands::do_quit,10],
    ["part",\&Harlie::Commands::do_part,10],
    ["join",\&Harlie::Commands::do_join,10],
    ["nick",\&Harlie::Commands::do_nick,10],
    ["module",\&Harlie::Commands::do_modules,10],
    ["uptime",\&Harlie::Commands::do_uptime,0]
);
```

And how would I be able to access the function references contained within? Currently, I can run them via:

```
@commands->[$foo]->(@bar);
```

Would I be correct in assuming it would simply be?:

```
$heap->{commands}->[$foo]->(@bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

To create/use an array on the POE heap, it's merely a case of wrapping the reference in "@{...}".
e.g.:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use POE;
use POE::Kernel;

POE::Session->create(
    inline_states =>{
        _start =>   \&foo,
        bar    => \&bar}  
);

sub foo{
    my ($kernel, $heap) = @_[KERNEL, HEAP];
    @{$heap->{fred}} = ("foo","bar","baz");
    $kernel->yield("bar");
}

sub bar{
    my ($kernel, $heap) = @_[KERNEL, HEAP];
    print "Length of array fred... " . ($#{$heap->{fred}}+1) . "\n";
    print "Contents of fred... ";
    foreach(@{$heap->{fred}}){
    print $_ . " ";  }
    print "\n";
}

POE::Kernel->run();
```

---

However, arrays of arrays are **not** that simple. The program that logically follows on from the above...

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use POE;
use POE::Kernel;

POE::Session->create(
    inline_states    => {
    _start =>    \&foo,
    bar    =>    \&bar
    }
    );

sub foo{
    my ($kernel, $heap) = @_[KERNEL, HEAP];

    @{$heap->{fred}} = (
        ["foo","bar","baz"],
        ["bob","george","dan"]
    );
    $kernel->yield("bar");
}

sub bar{
    my ($kernel, $heap) = @_[KERNEL, HEAP];
    print "Length of array fred... " . ($#{$heap->{fred}}+1) . "\n";
    print @{$heap->{fred}}[0][0];

}

POE::Kernel->run();
```

...merely gives the following error.

> perl ../poe-test.pl
>
> syntax error at ../poe-test.pl line 26, near "]["
>
> Execution of ../poe-test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.`

Comment: `print @{$heap->{fred}}[0][0];`

should be

`print ${$heap->{fred}}[0][0];`

or

`print $heap->{fred}->[0][0];`